# How can I make a welcome command in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

The welcome message never sends and I don't get any errors, please help

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
  guild = member.guild
  channel = guild.get_channel(912778268803993685)

  embed=discord.Embed(title="Welcome {member.mention}!",description=f"{member.mention} Has joined us. Go to #info for more information")
  embed.set_footer(text=f"Made by  Hydro#5419")
  await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: I assume your last line is part of the function and you just copy-pasted it incorrectly?

Comment: I copy and pasted it wrong here, it's in the correct indentation in my code

Comment: Yeah, I can't see anything wrong with this code... do your other bot message commands work? Also double-check that the bot is in the right server and you are joining a new user to that server - seems obvious, but I've made worse mistakes.

Comment: You've never defined channel.

Comment: @MaikHasler Defined in line 4. `channel = guild.get_channel(912778268803993685)`

Comment: Have you enabled the members intent?

Comment: Yeah I have

All my code is working fine, I have about 400 lines of code with no errors

Comment: try using `client.get_channel(id)` instead of `guild.get_channel(id)`

Comment: Maybe you haven't got `SERVER MEMBERS INTENT`? You can enable it [here](https://discord.com/developers/applications/) .

Comment: It still doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
channel = client.get_channel()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
@bot.event

async def on_member_join (member):
    channel = bot.get_channel ( 902539930566271027 )

    role = discord.utils.get (member.guild.roles, id=891029501520269373)
    print (f'{member.name} join the servers')
    await member.add_roles( role )
    await channel.send( embed = discord.Embed( description = f'Welcome {member.mention}', color = 0x0c0c0c))
```